# Using cell value in formula

Tags: variables, stata, stata-macros

If I have a variable in Stata that has a number, can I use that value embedded in a formula?

For example, I variable days (`days`) and for each individual I want to use that number in a second formula:

```
ID    Days    var_x_1    var_x_2    var_x_3    var_x_4    var_x_5    var_x_6
A      2        7           8          9          10         2          1
B      1        1           7          1          11         12         11
C      6        7           9          2          12         6          12
D      2        2           4          3          17         7          18

gen new_var = var_x_DAYS
```

Variable `new_var` would take the value in `Days` and pull the corresponding from the `var_x` list:

```
ID new_var
A    8
B    1
C    12
D    4
```

I have tried:

```
local DaysUse = Days
g new_var = var_x_`DaysUse'
```

However, this did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That last statement could be perfectly legal; it just doesn't do what you want. Consider

```
local DaysUse = Days
g new_var = var_x_`DaysUse'
```

A local macro is just some text. More crucially, it is a text constant or scalar, not a variable or vector of text elements. Here Stata will understand you as wanting

```
local DaysUse = Days[1]
```

so that your `local` will contain the string `2`, at least for your example, so that

```
g new_var = var_x_2
```

will be the net result after macro substitution. If you went

```
local DaysUse = "Days"
```

you would get

```
g new_var = var_x_Days
```

which is no use here.

There is more positive technique for your problem.

```
gen new_var = . 
quietly forval j = 1/6 { 
    replace new_var = var_x_`j' if Days == `j' 
}
```

Stata has something a little like what you want. Consider

```
sysuse auto, clear
set seed 2803 
gen index = ceil(runiform() * 74)
gen bsample_mpg_1 = mpg[index]
gen bsample_mpg_2 = mpg[ceil(runiform() * 74]
```

as two ways of getting bootstrap samples in place. But that doesn't extend to what you asked for.